# How can I get a list of all inline-styles?

Tags: javascript, css

There's an easy way to find all current attributes on an HTMLElement using `el.attributes`, but I can't find an equivalent for inline-styles. I've tried seeing if anyone else ran into this problem but there seems to be no relative results.

Doing something like this I was able to find all *possible* styles, but it also included all the functions and irrelevant data.

```
for( var style in el.style ){ 
    console.log(el.style[style]); 
}
```

This is a very wasteful computation for a loop that can be as large as 300+ iterations with a potential of 100% of the inline-styles not actually set to anything. Is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Ah, I wasn't using Jquery. Sorry about the confusing dollar sign. $0 is a chrome dev-tool functionality that allows you to work with the currently selected element in the console.

Comment: It has a JS answer if not mistaken.. @Lemony

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs looks like it's hidden in there. Though, there are multiple small distinctions between my question and that question and my questions is more specific about just the inline-styles.

Comment: You are absolute right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I did have the answer before posting this question, but I was going to ask it anyways and think it would be helpful to other people*

The style object returned by nodes has a `length` property which is the number of currently defined inline-styles. You can use this property to loop over the style object as an array-like structure and each index returns the name that is defined.

Example:

```
for (var i = 0, l = el.style.length; i < l; i++){
    console.log(el.style[i]); // an active inline-style
}
```

Comment: Yes it is helpful i think ^^

Comment: `el.style.map((x,y) => console.log(x));`

Comment: Oops, lemme remedy with some more ES6! `Array.from(el.style).map((x,y) => console.log(x));`

Comment: @SterlingArcher works much nicer! Thank you :). I'm still doing old-school js haha. Learning the quirks of ES6 is my next project.

Comment: Come to the JS chat room if you need help. Lotta pros in there

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'll take your word! Aren't chat-rooms getting removed from stack in the future though?

Comment: thanks. but you have an error in you code is "el.style" not "el.styles"  .. without final 's'

Comment: @Doua Beri, I believe this code is directly from a working snippet. What are you testing with?

Comment: @FreddyJones "for( var i = 0, l = el.styles.length; "  there is no el.styles ; the code works great with "el.style"   tested with firefox and chrome

Comment: For a more complete answer, check my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need an array of set inline CSS properties, you can simply convert the `style` of the element to an array with spread syntax or `Array.from`.

```js
function getInlineStyleProperties(elem){
  return [...elem.style];
}
console.log(getInlineStyleProperties(document.querySelector('div')));
```

```html
<div style="height: 20px; color: red;"></div>
```

To get an object mapping the set properties to their values, you can convert the `style` of the element to an array with spread syntax to get all the set properties, map over it to create an array of key-value pairs, and use `Object.fromEntries` to convert it to an object.

```js
function getInlineStyles(elem){
  return Object.fromEntries([...elem.style].map(x => [x, elem.style[x]]));
}
console.log(getInlineStyles(document.querySelector('div')));
```

```html
<div style="height: 20px; color: red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern way of doing it is this:

```js
function getInlineStyle (element) {
  return Array.from(element.style).reduce((style, name) => {
    style[name] = element.style[name]
    return style
  }, {})
}

const div = document.getElementById('foo')
console.log(getInlineStyle(div))
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="width: 100px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
```